# Android: Data is available still getting error NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am new in android development..I want to insert `json string` in `Sqlite database` and getting error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1212, result=0, data=null} to activity : java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

here is my code :

DbAdapter.java

```
   static final String DATABASE_FEEDBACK="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+" feedbackjson "+
        "("+"FeedbackId"+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+" JSON text, Fullname text, Email text, AdminId text);";


 public void insertJSONFeedback(String json,String fullName,String email)
{
    Log.i("Data Insert reached", "yes");

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    Log.i("JSON STRING to be insert1",json);
    newValues.put("JSON", json);
    newValues.put("Fullname",fullName);
    newValues.put("Email",email);
    newValues.put("AdminId","1");
    db.insert("feedbackjson", null, newValues);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Data Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("context", "Toast");

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
DbAdapter databaseadapter;

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    databaseadapter=new DbAdapter (this);
    databaseadapter=databaseadapter.open();
}


 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("Result Code", resultCode + "");


    fullName_et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_et);
    email_et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_et);

    String detailInformation = "";
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> userFields = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    userFields = UtilityClass.EDIT_PROFILE_WITH_FIELD_NAME;

    String fieldValueAndPrivacy = null;// = new

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(userFields, LinkedHashMap.class);

    Log.i("User Fields",json);

    databaseadapter.insertJSONFeedback(json, fullName_et.getText().toString(), email_et.getText().toString());

    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> editProfileHashValues = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    Iterator fieldIterator = userFields.entrySet().iterator();
    while (fieldIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry fieldPairs = (Map.Entry) fieldIterator.next();
        String fieldName = (String) fieldPairs.getKey();
        String fieldRunTimeValue = (String) fieldPairs.getValue();
        detailInformation += fieldName + " => " + fieldRunTimeValue
                + "\n";
        Log.i("Detail Information", detailInformation);
    }
}
```

Here My json String :: `{"Full Name":"gyt","Email Address":"ggfh","Contact Number":"987654568","Rate Quality of Food":"2.5","Service Quality":"3.0","Overall Experience":"3.0","Restaurant Branch":"Vadodara","Comments":"okh"}`

and I got error `java.lang.NullPointerException` in this line:

> databaseadapter.insertJSONFeedback(json,
>   fullName_et.getText().toString(), email_et.getText().toString());

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out wich value is null.

Comment: there is no any value which is null...i already checked that...still geting error nullpointerexception..Is there any other reason?not to use db in activity result or any other...

Comment: Add the complete LogCat

Comment: do one thing and check it crashes or not... add both line databaseadapter=new DbAdapter (this);
    databaseadapter=databaseadapter.open(); in onActivityResult() ...

Comment: as it seems your "databaseadapter" object is reference to null..hence it throws nullpointerexception ....

Comment: post the initialization of databaseadapter object

Comment: @AngadTiwari: Its work to put databaseadapter=new DbAdapter (this);  line in result..thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it seems your "databaseadapter" object is reference to null..hence it throws nullpointerexception ....

> do one thing and check it crashes or not... add both line databaseadapter=new DbAdapter (this); databaseadapter=databaseadapter.open(); in onActivityResult() ...

Answer (score 0):

you have missed `setContentView(int resId)` in `onCreate()` of your activity.

Comment: I have not written whole code here ...It is already available in my code but cant write here whole page code..only related data to be written

Comment: @Ammy put your complete Logcat.